# How to get a substring using sed being the pattern "/"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

I have  the following string:

/book/A00001/2018/01/15/Chamber_Music

And I want to get using the sed command:

/book/A00001/2018/01/15/

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe are you looking for: `sed "s/\(.*\)Chamber_Music/\1/g"`

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `sed`, you can use normal shell string handling:

```
filename='gash.txt'
new_filename="$filename.new"

while read line
do
    line=${line%/*}
    echo $line 

done <"$filename" >"$new_filename"  

#mv "$new_filename" "$filename"     # Commented out to be optional
```

Given your input in your second question:

```
/book/A00001/2018/01/15
/book/A00001/2018/01/15
/book/A00001/2018/01/15
/book/A00001/2018/01/15
/book/A00001/2018/01/15
/book/A00001/2018/01/15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the regexp `sed` delimiter.... see the `s` command documentation.  If you use, e.g.

```
sed 's:([a-zA-Z0-9/]*)[a-zA-Z]*$:\1:'
```

then, the `/` loses its special treatment and the `:` character assumes it.  Of course, you can store the matching pattern in an environment variable, before to feed it to `sed(1)`, and substitute all `/` into `\/` to escape every `/`.

```
pattern=`echo "([a-zA-Z0-9/])[a-zA-Z]*\$" | sed 's/\//\\//'`
sed "s/${pattern}/\\1/"
```

but this is more complex.